# Using dependency injection and mocking it with gmock

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, googlemock

I have implemented a Dependency Injection pattern in my code. I did that to be able to mock a service using gmock. The DI implementation works in production code, however, I am having trouble with my test setup. When using the EXPECT_CALL macro, I get "expression must have class type" error. I believe this is related to the way I designed the dependency, but I can't find an alternative solution (lack of experience). I have browsed previous threads on similar issues, but none helped. Would you be kind to take a look at the code below and hint possible workarounds (simplified code example using a Car-Engine interface)?

```
// Engine interface class with pure virtual functions
class IEngine
{
public:
    virtual ~IEngine() = default;
    virtual void start() = 0;
    virtual void stop() = 0;
};


// A V8Engine class implementing this interface
class V8Engine : public IEngine
{
public:
    void start() override { std::cout << "V8 Engine started\n"; };
    void stop() override { std::cout << "V8 Engine stopped\n"; };
};


// Car.h file
class Car
{
public:
    Car(IEngine *engineService);
    void Drive();
private:
    IEngine* mEngine = nullptr;
};


// Car.cpp file
Car::Car(IEngine* engineService)
    : mEngine(engineService)
{
    if (mEngine == nullptr)
    {
        throw std::invalid_argument("service must not be null");
    }
}

void Car::Drive()
{
    mEngine->start();
    mEngine->stop();
}
```

I would like to be able to mock the engine implementation and instead of using a "real V8Engine", utilize the mock. Here is how I set up my test:

```
class MockEngine : public IEngine
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, start, (), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, stop, (), (override));
};

TEST(TestCarClass, TestCarWithMockEngine)
{
    IEngine *mockEngine = new MockEngine;
    Car carUnderTest(mockEngine);
    carUnderTest.Drive();

    EXPECT_CALL(mockEngine, start()); // This is the part where I get the error due to invalid mockEngine setup
}
```

Comment: `EXPECT_CALL` should be called before code to test (`carUnderTest.Drive()`).

Comment: To avoid unneeded `new`: `MockEngine mock; Car car(&mock);` and it will fix `EXPECT_CALL` which expect mock and not pointer on mock.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. When I was doing unit tests in C# with NUnit, the expected calls always came after the code to test, thus the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPECT_CALL` expects mock object as first parameter, you pass reference to mock.

either use `*mockEngine`:

```
TEST(TestCarClass, TestCarWithMockEngine)
{
    IEngine *mockEngine = new MockEngine;
    Car carUnderTest(mockEngine);

    EXPECT_CALL(*mockEngine, start());

    carUnderTest.Drive();
}
```

or avoid allocation directly:

```
TEST(TestCarClass, TestCarWithMockEngine)
{
    MockEngine mockEngine;
    Car carUnderTest(&mockEngine);

    EXPECT_CALL(mockEngine, start());

    carUnderTest.Drive();
}
```